# using jquery post, return what if not success?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

im using jquery.post. My problem is that i dont know what to return if its not success from my controller? Lets say if modelstate is not valid, check my controller below.

```
public ActionResult SendNewsLetter(FooterViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var email = _newsletterService.GetAll().Where(x => x.Email == viewModel.Email).SingleOrDefault();

                if (email == null)
                {
                    _newsletterService.Save(new NewsletterEmail() { AddedDate = DateTime.Now, Email = viewModel.Email, IdGuid = GenerateGuid.Generate() });
                    _email.Send(viewModel.Email, "Title", "body", AppSetting.Value(Key.Email()));
                }
                else
                {
                    _newsletterService.Delete(email.Id);
                }

                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return Content(FeedBackMessages.NewsletterSuccess());
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //What to put here?
            }

        }

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            //What to put here?
            return Content("");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

my jquery

```
$('#formNewsletter').submit(function () {
                $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) { success(data); });
                return false;
            });
function success(message) {
            //TODO the real success handle
            alert(message);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

append this to your post() method to do something on an error

```
$.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) { success(data); });
                return false;
            }).error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

Edit:

To return the empty string, I would return a `JsonResult`. It's a subclass of `ActionResult` and has a property called Data. You can add json variables into this that can be interpretted by javascript into js variables. If you are not familar with JSON go here http://www.json.org/

Very easy though, should look something like this:

```
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new JsonResult() { Data = "'Message' : ''" };
            //will return a json result with the data set to have a variable `Message` that is an empty string
        }
```

On the Js side it looks like this:

```
      $('#formNewsletter').submit(function () {
            $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) { success(data); });
            return false;
        });

    function success(data) {
        //TODO the real success handle
        alert(data.Message); //this should do it, I could be wrong, if so put a break point here and inspect the data object in firebug or dev tools to see where the `Message` json variable is stored.
    };
```

Comment: ill do that thanks. but if you look at my controller, if the modelstate is not vaild and if its a Request.IsAjaxRequest i return a empty string wich wont be a error. how do i go about that?

Comment: @Dejan.S I added an edit to answer your second question. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET but I assume that `Content(FeedBackMessages.NewsletterSuccess())` transforms objects to a corresponding HTTP response, in this particular case possibly a localized `String` to a response with `Content-Type: text/plain`.

My suggestion would be to wrap the success message into a result object which does not only contain a success or error message but also the corresponding state, like

```
class Result {
    boolean success
    String message
}
```

Assuming that `Content()` transforms objects to JSON, you could return a `Result` object with `success=false` and evaluate this in your jQuery success handler. (Update: see Matthew Cox' answer to see how to create a JSON result object.)

```
$.post(this.action,
    $(this).serialize(),
    function (data) {
        // Data transport went fine, now check the application logic result:
        if (data.success) {
            success(data.message);
        } else {
            failure(data.message);
        }
    }
);
```

Maybe there's a more straightforward, native ASP.NET approach, but this one works generally well and JSON is well supported on JS client-side.